# React Router v6 browser refresh and url bar problem

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using `react-router@6` and `createBrowseRouter`. Navigating via links on page works well and the URL is updating, but when refreshing or trying to access the path directly, the user is sent to the index route.

My basic router structure looks like this:

Routes.js

```
const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <Route
      path="/"
      element={
        <Root
          ...some props
        />
      }
      loader={some loader...}
      action={some action...}
    >
      <Route index element={<Home />} exact />
      <Route path="templates/:id">
        <Route
          index
          element={<Document />}
          errorElement={some error element...}
          loader={some loader...}
          action={some action...}
        />
        <Route
          path="edit"
          element={
            <EditDocument ...some props />
          }
          loader={some loader...}
          action={some action...}
        />
      </Route>
      <Route path="settings" element={<Settings />} />
    </Route>
  )
)
```

So basically a root route with some nested routes. At the bottom of this component, I'm returning like this: `return <RouterProvider router={router} />;`

The Routes component in the Routes.js is rendered via an App.js, in which I'm loading some data and passing that data via props (to the Routes component). The App.js is rendered via index.js.

My feeling is that the general structure of my routes is incorrect, but I'm not sure. I believe I followed some official React Router v6 sample code.

Comment: Are you saying you've navigated to *some* page in the app, say `"/templates/123/edit"` rendering `EditDocument`, and you reload the page and get navigated to `"/"` and the `Home` component is rendered? Do you have some code where issuing any sort of redirect, like maybe an authentication check somewhere?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DrewReese! Indeed my Routes component (above) is returned from a component which checks the local storage of a current user as well as access tokens. That App.js is wrapped by index.js and another context. You think that could be the reason React Router is not refreshing on the current URL as well as that that URL is not reachable via that direct link?

Comment: I was a dumb*** / had a useEffect that was redirecting to index. And render.com (where I'm deploying) shows how to set up a redirect, so that client site routing works: https://render.com/docs/deploy-create-react-app#using-client-side-routing — Thank you!